# php inserting data in mysql from json runs too slowly

Tags: php, mysql, json, pdo

I have the following code to read a JSON and store the results in a DDBB.
The code works, but it takes more than a minute to insert just 400 records.
If I open the json, it loads pretty fast.
What I'm doing wrong?

```
    $db = new PDO('', '', '');
    $db->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);
    if(tableExists($db, 'locations') == 1)
    {
        $sql=$db->prepare("DROP TABLE locations");
        $sql->execute();
    }
    $sql ="CREATE TABLE `locations` (id INT(6) UNSIGNED AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY, evid INT(6) NOT NULL, place VARCHAR(150), country VARCHAR(150), reg_date TIMESTAMP)" ;
    $db->exec($sql);
    $json = file_get_contents('thejson.php');
    $data = array();
    $data = json_decode($json); 
    foreach ($data as $key => $object) 
    {
        if(is_object($object))
        {
            $id = $object->id;
            $place = $object->name;
            $country = substr(strrchr($object->name, "-"), 2);
            $stmt = $db->prepare("INSERT INTO `locations` (evid, place, country) VALUES (:evid, :places, :country)");
            $stmt->bindValue(':evid', $id, PDO::PARAM_INT);
            $stmt->bindValue(':places', $place, PDO::PARAM_STR);  
            $stmt->bindValue(':country', $country, PDO::PARAM_STR);      
            $stmt->execute();
        }
    }
```

Comment: why don't you insert the full array in single query instead of running a loop for each row

Comment: To improve the speed you should not create the key in the beginning. Insert the records without the key. Create the key at the end of the insert process.

Comment: Pavan Jiwnani, what do you mean exactly? Franz Holzinger, I don't understand what do you mean neither, can you give me an example?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The first two things I would try would be moving the prepare outside the loop, and wrapping it in a transaction:

```
try {
    $db->beginTransaction();
    $stmt = $db->prepare("INSERT INTO `locations` (evid, place, country) VALUES (:evid, :places, :country)");

    foreach ($data as $key => $object) 
    {
        if(is_object($object))
        {
            $id = $object->id;
            $place = $object->name;
            $country = substr(strrchr($object->name, "-"), 2);
            
            $stmt->bindValue(':evid', $id, PDO::PARAM_INT);
            $stmt->bindValue(':places', $place, PDO::PARAM_STR);  
            $stmt->bindValue(':country', $country, PDO::PARAM_STR);      
            $stmt->execute();
        }
    }

    $db->commit();

} catch (Exception $e) {
    $db->rollBack();
    throw $e;
}
```

Another thing you could do is try using `bindParam` to bind the vars by reference - this way you only need to call `bindParam` once on each variable name at the start, then just overwrite the values of those variables on each iteration and call execute.

```
try {
    $db->beginTransaction();
    $stmt = $db->prepare("INSERT INTO `locations` (evid, place, country) VALUES (:evid, :places, :country)");
     $id = 0;
     $place = '';
     $country = '';

     $stmt->bindParam(':evid', $id, PDO::PARAM_INT);
     $stmt->bindParam(':places', $place, PDO::PARAM_STR);  
     $stmt->bindParam(':country', $country, PDO::PARAM_STR); 

    foreach ($data as $key => $object) 
    {
        if(is_object($object))
        {
            $id = $object->id;
            $place = $object->name;
            $country = substr(strrchr($object->name, "-"), 2);
            $stmt->execute();
        }
    }

    $db->commit();

} catch (Exception $e) {
    $db->rollBack();
    throw $e;
}
```

Similar to this instead of calling `bind*` you could just pass the values in via `execute`:

```
try {
    $db->beginTransaction();
    $stmt = $db->prepare("INSERT INTO `locations` (evid, place, country) VALUES (:evid, :places, :country)");

    foreach ($data as $key => $object) 
    {
        if(is_object($object))
        {
            $params = array(
                ':id' => $object->id,
                ':places' => $object->name,
                ':country' => substr(strrchr($object->name, "-"), 2)
            );
                  
            $stmt->execute($params);
        }
    }

    $db->commit();

} catch (Exception $e) {
    $db->rollBack();
    throw $e;
}
```

I suspect using a transaction will get you a performance gain, but I don't know that there will be a ton of difference between switching up the binding methods.

Your best bet is probably to insert all the records in a single query as @PavanJiwnani suggests:

```
// first we need to compile a structure of only items 
// we will insert with the values properly transformed

$insertData = array_map(function ($object) {
     if (is_object($object)) {
        return array(
            $object->id,
            $object->name,
            substr(strrchr($object->name, "-"), 2)
        );
     } else {
       return false;
     }
}, $data);

// filter out the FALSE values
$insertData = array_filter($insertData);

// get the number of records we have to insert
$nbRecords = count($insertData);

// $records is an array containing a (?,?,?) 
// for each item we want to insert
$records = array_fill(0, $nbRecords, '(?,?,?)');

// now use sprintf and implode to generate the SQL like:
// INSERT INTO `locations` (evid, place, country) VALUES (?,?,?),(?,?,?),(?,?,?),(?,?,?)
$sql = sprintf(
    'INSERT INTO `locations` (evid, place, country) VALUES %s',   
    implode(',', $records)
);

$stmt = $db->prepare($sql);

// Now we need to flatten our array of insert values as that is what 
// will be expected by execute()
$params = array();
foreach ($insertData as $datum) {
   $params = array_merge($params, $datum);
}

// and finally we attempt to execute
$stmt->execute($params);
```

Comment: The last option works like a charm, thanks a lot for your help. Now it looks obvious and smart for me, but I wasn't able to find the solution. Only one thing more "get_object_vars" is needed in order to convert the object into an array.
Thanks for your help!

Comment: Hmm.. why did you need `get_object_vars`? all that should be taken care of with the call to `array_map`

Comment: If I use it like you did it, the PHP launches an error complaining about the second argument of array_map not being an array (in fact it is an object)

Comment: Oh.. i thought it was an array array of objects ie. `[{"name":"somename","id":1}]`... If that is the case you should use `json_decode($jsonString, true)` then it will decode as an associative array removing the need to use `get_object_vars` (which i personally find dirty and to be avoided).

Answer (score 0):

Try to echo timestamps with milliseconds to see what is running slow. Probably executing 400 insert queries (including opening/closing connections).

Answer (score 0):

There are many factors that affects the performance of the database, please provide detailed information about the database system, PHP version and related hardware.

The bottleneck could be at:

```
file_get_contents('thejson.php')
```

if the JSON contents are fetched from a remote host, i.e. DB is running normally, network is slow.

You may also want to consider move:

```
$stmt = $db->prepare("INSERT INTO `locations` (evid, place, country) VALUES (:evid, :places, :country)");
```

out of the foreach loop.

Comment: I have move the prepare outside of the loop, but this doesn't fix the problem. If I open thejson.php straight, it serves the json quickly, so I'm not sure if this can be the problem. The server is configuration is Linux: PHP 5.3.10, MySQL 5.5.